# ASP.NET_SessionId cookie behavior explanation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, iis-7

I have a `MVC ASP.NET` project and have the following action filter attribute

```cs
public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

    if (ctx.Session != null)
    {
        if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
            if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
            {
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = "Session Timeout. Redirecting...", ContentType = "application/json" };
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 440;
                }
                else
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary 
                        {
                            { "Controller", "Error" },
                            { "Action", "SessionTimeout" }
                        });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to redirect to `SessionTimeout` action which displays an error page whenever the IIS session times out.

Most of the time it works fine but I found that sometimes, especially the very first time I start the application, this code will **run into the `else` block** and thus redirect to the error page which is unwanted as this is the first visit from users' view.

*(here "**first**" means a long enough time since last time running the application, say a couple of days)*

To run into the `else` block, it means the session is a new session but there exists `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie as well.

My question is: Why is this happening? Is this behavior normal & expected?

(I do not need a solution, just some explanation to the behavior is fine...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Asp.Net Session` cookie is typically a *session* cookie. That is, it is removed by the browser once all browser windows are closed down. If, however a user leaves his/her browser open and does something else for a while, long enough for the `Asp.Net Session` to expire on the server and then comes back to your site, then the browser will send the cookie, the server will not recognize it and start a new session. In that case you will see the issue you described.

Some browsers also have some kind of *restore previous session* functionality which can mean that cookies that would otherwise have been removed will continue to exist even if the browser was closed in between.

I haven't tested this, but you might be able to recognize this situation by comparing the ID of the new `Asp.Net Session` to the value in the cookie...

Comment: Thanks...that's a bit more clear to me now. For closing the browser (in order to remove this session cookie), does it mean to close all tabs of the browser? (I am using Chrome)

Comment: Yes, different browser tabs usually share the same client session. Even different browser windows usually share the same client session.